# unable to free mat image which is created from iplimage

Tags: c++, opencv

//  src is a IplImage, using in my code if i write the below code in a //function will it free the memory
    Mat m1(src);
    m1.release();  //don't free memory
    cvReleaseImage(&src);  //free memory

Comment: whenever possible don't mix Mat and IplImage http://answers.opencv.org/question/14285/how-to-free-memory-through-cvmat/

Comment: Though terse, this question is perfectly valid and clear

Answer (score 1):

Use `Mat m1 = imread("temp.jpg")` instead. Problem is that `Mat` doesn't free memory that it didn't allocate - it was allocated with `cvLoadImage`. When you put `IplImage` pointer to the constructor of `Mat`, it doesn't copy anything but instead creates an object which points to the original `IplImage` memory.